# Map have some lags after data is passed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

I'm using MapKit to show some map in the app, the problem is when I'm trying to pass data after button is tapped, the second mapview is laggy, and doesn't work as it should:

This is the code for showing first map:

```
struct FirstMapView: View{
@ObservedObject var staffVM: StaffViewModel
var body: some View{
    Map(coordinateRegion: staffVM.mapRegionBinding, annotationItems: staffVM.locations) { location in
                            MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinates?[0] ?? 0, longitude: location.coordinates?[1] ?? 0)) {
                                ZStack{
                                    Circle()
                                       .fill(Color("red").opacity(0.05))
                                       .frame(width:100, height:100)
                                    Image("pincode")
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .frame(height:200)
 .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $staffVM.navigateToBiggerMap) {
        LeadLocationMapView(staffVM: staffVM)
        
    }
}
}
```

This is ViewModel:

```
@Published var mapRegion: MKCoordinateRegion?


var mapRegionBinding: Binding<MKCoordinateRegion> {
    Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>(
        get: {
            guard let region = self.mapRegion else {
                return MKCoordinateRegion()
            }
            return region
        },
        set: { newRegion in
            self.mapRegion = newRegion
        }
    )
}
```

and this is the func inside viewModel:

```
  func setUpForLeadDetails(serverId: String, profilePicture: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, leadCoordinates:[Double], locations: LocationLead, notes: String, phoneNumber: String, date: String, leadId: String) {
        self.serverId = serverId
        self.profilePicture = profilePicture
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.navigateToLeadDetails = true
        self.leadCoordinates = leadCoordinates
        
        let latitude = leadCoordinates.first ?? 0.0
        let longitude = leadCoordinates.last ?? 0.0
        
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
        self.mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)
        self.locationCenter = center
        self.locations.append(locations)
        
        self.notes = notes
        self.stringDate = date
        self.leadId = leadId
        
        print("Activated \(self.navigateToLeadDetails)")
        print("Coordinates are: \(self.leadCoordinates)")
    }
```

And this is the bigger screen of leads:

```
struct LeadLocationMapView: View {
    @ObservedObject var staffVM: StaffViewModel 
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Map(coordinateRegion: staffVM.mapRegionBinding)
       
          
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

This is the parent view where ViewModel was initialized:

```
struct ParentView: View{
var body: some View{
    @StateObject var staffVM: StaffViewModel = StaffViewModel?
        VStack{
              ForEach(staffLeadsDataInfo) { item in
                                                StaffLead(name: "\(item.firstName ?? "") \(item.lastName ?? "")", phoneNumber: "\(staffVM.maskPhoneNumber(item.phoneNumber ?? ""))", referralId: "\(item.referralID ?? "")", date:"\(staffVM.convertDateFormat(item.createdAt ?? "Unknown"))", color:staffVM.colors.randomElement() ?? Color.cyan)
                                                    .onTapGesture {
                                                       staffVM.setUpForLeadDetails(serverId: item.product?.id ?? "", profilePicture: item.agent?.picture ?? "", firstName: item.agent?.firstName ?? "", lastName: item.agent?.lastName ?? "", leadCoordinates: item.location?.coordinates ?? [-1.286389, 36.817223], locations: item.location ?? LocationLead(type: "", coordinates: [0, 0], street1: "", street2: "", state: "", city: ""), notes:item.visitInformation?.notes ?? "", phoneNumber: item.phoneNumber ?? "", date:item.createdAt ?? "", leadId: item.serverId ?? "")
                
            
             staffVM.navigateToFirstMap.toggle()                                         
            
            }
            
            }
        } .navigationDestination(isPresented: $staffVM.navigateToFirstMan) {
                FirstMapView(staffVM: staffVM).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
}
}
```

On the parent screen I'm using .fullscreencover(isPresented), so when button is tapped, the screen with bigger map will popup, but screen is a laggy, can't zoom in, out...

Edit: But when it's `@StateObject`, it works normally.

Comment: `But when it's @StateObject, it works normally.`, well use `@StateObject` then, what is the problem.

Comment: The problem is because I need those data(coordinate) that I'm sending from the parent

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is `data(coordinate)` and where is the code of sending those from the parent. 
Where and how do you use `@StateObject`? Where is the code for `.fullscreencover(...)`?

Comment: This is **not** a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
 
You should not declare `@StateObject var staffVM: ...` inside the `body` of your `ParentView`.
You should declare `@StateObject var staffVM = StaffViewModel()` not `StaffViewModel?`
 and place it outside the `body` of your `ParentView`.

Comment: Try without the view models